# How to create a table on top of HDFS folders with subfolders and multiple csv files

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

We have a hdfs folder with structure like `/data/year/day/.csvfiles`,
so we have multiple csv files stored per day in hdfs folders
e.g. `/finance/2019/20190101/ multiple csv files`. 
Similarly, there will be 365 folders in `/finance/2019/` for 365 days of a year.
I would like to create a Hive table on top of `/finance/2019/` so I can query all data, however my create table only works if I specify specific folder such as `/finance/2019/20190101/`, and then query returns resultset.
If I try to create table with location as `/finance/2019/` the table cannot retrieve any data and the result is always 0.

Comment: You can also make use of partitioning and bucketing concepts for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

To read data from **`subdirectories`** set these properties!

```
hive> SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE;
hive> SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
```

Try to select the data from the hive table again.

---

In case if you don't want to set these properties everytime in hive shell then add these properties in your **`hive-site.xml`** file

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.dir.recursive</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```